# Automorphism of the upper half plane on $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-sphere

I know that the automorphisms of the upper half plane  $\mathbb C$ have the form $F_A=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, where $\det A=ad-bc\neq0$. I want to show that if it preserves $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$, then $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R$ and $\det A>0$. I can prove that the determinant will be positive if $a,b,c,d$ are reals, but I can not show the first.

I know that $F_A$ is 2-transitive, this meaning that if I choose $p,q,r$ distinct points and $p',q',r' $ also distinct points, then there is a choice of $A$ such that $F_A(p)=p',F_A(q)=q',F_A(r)=r'$, my professor said that with a good choice of the image could give me that the coeficients are real.

Thanks in advance

Comment: trying picking all three points on $\mathbf{R}$

Comment: remember once you know where 3 points go you have fully defined the transformation. Maybe take one of them to be $\infty$

Comment: What I tried was to pick the image to be $0, \infty, 1$, then I get that $-b/a$, $-d/c$ and $\frac{ar+b}{cr+d}$ are real numbers, if I show that one of them is real I get the result, but I did not find a way to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an automorphism preserves $\Bbb R$, then there must be three real numbers that are sent to real numbers. This gives three homogenous linear equations with real coefficients when solving for $a,b,c,d$, so $a,b,c,d$ may be taken to be real.

Comment: This will imply that one of them is not real at least, so that $A$ is not a real matrix, then the counter positive says that if $A$ is a real matrix then it presearves $\mathbb R$, the converse of what I want to prove

Comment: @e.turatti You're right, I was thinking the wrong way. How about now?

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, but I can't get from the conditions obtained that they are real numbers

Comment: You want to solve three simultaneous equations like $2a+b=8c+4d$ (if we happen to have $2\mapsto 4$, and want to use that). In these three equations all coefficients are real, and these equations are all linear and homogenous. That necessarily gives a continuous family of real solutions.

Comment: If I take three points $p,q,r$ that are real, I can set the image to be $0, \infty, 1$, then I get the equation $ap+b=0$, $cq+d=0$, $ar+b-cr-d=0$, that are the three homogeneous equations, but from this I am not being able to prove what you said, that this shoud have real coefficients.

I can see that if one of them is real, then all the others are going to be real, but I can't assure this first one being real

Comment: what I get is that $a/c$, $a/b$, $c/d$ are real numbers, but I can't see how to go on with that

Comment: This system that you describes indeed has a continous family of solutions, but it is a $1$-dimensional family over the field I am considering, no? So in such case, over $\mathbb C$

Comment: @e.turatti Yes, and if $a$ happens to be non-zero, you can divide all the coefficients by $a$, and you get ...? If $a$ is zero, but $b$ is non-zero, you can divide them all by $b$, and you get ...? I personally think focusing on $1, 0$ and $\infty$ is superfluous and unnecessary.

Comment: @Arthur Is it possible to write both $f(z)=\frac{z−i}{z+i}$ and $g(z)=\frac{z}{z+i}$ in the $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ forms? I've been told they're both automorphisms of the upper half plane of $\mathbb{C}$, though I doubt it.

Comment: @Derpp You have $f(1)=-i$ and $g(0)=-i$, so they map (at least parts of) the boundary of the upper half plane out of the upper half plane. Thus they cannot be automorphisms of the upper half plane.